# Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

rest api method

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    ResponseEntity<DocumentBaseResponse> createAsset(
            @Valid @RequestPart("requestBody") MyClass jsonPart,
            @Valid @NotNull @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file);
```

error console

```
2023-07-12 10:59:48.128 WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported]
```

swagger result

```
{
  "timestamp": "2023-07-12T08:59:48.135+00:00",
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "path": "/v1/test"
}
```

triggers a 415 error if I try to perform this method

Comment: Your endpoint accepts `multipart/form-data` content type only, but the request has `application/octet-stream` as Content-Type header. I suppose you are using Postman or something like that. If I'm right, then change the body settings in that application.

Comment: I can reproduce your case. It looks like Swagger UI can't handle it correctly. Testing with Postman works fine. However only if I add a content type definition (application/json) to the request part with JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few irregularities that you need to address

1. MediaType.MULTIPART_FORMDATA is not json, but your application, you're expecting RequestBody to be of type application/json which the system should reject
2. Are you trying to upload an exe file? If you're uploading json then the Content-Type should be application/json. On the other hand application/octet-stream is usually an exe file. for a binary file with arbitrary content, the content-type should be binary/octet-stream

hope that helps

Comment: hello i send file pdf and json string for cast to  java class